# Unable to Cancel the Alarm defined in kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, alarm

**I was creating the Alarm by defined below method**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmClockReceiver.class);
    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putSerializable(ALARM_CLOCK, dosesReminder);
    intent.putExtra(ALARM_CLOCK_BUNDLE, bundle);
    intent.putExtra("MedicineName", dosesReminder.getMedicine_name());
    String MedicineTime = "";
    if (dosesReminder.getMorning_dosed().equals("1")) {
        MedicineTime = "1 Morning ";
    }
    if (dosesReminder.getAfter_noon_dosed().equals("1")) {
        MedicineTime = MedicineTime + "1 Afternoon ";
    }
    if (dosesReminder.getEvening_dosed().equals("1")) {
        MedicineTime = MedicineTime + "1 Evening ";
    }
    intent.putExtra("MedicineTime", MedicineTime);
    Log.e("Alarm Id---", "" + alarm_id);
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, Integer.parseInt(alarm_id), intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

    long nextTime = calculateNextTime(alarm.hour,
            alarm.minute, getWeeks(alarm));
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime, pi);
    else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.KITKAT) {
        alarmManager.setExact(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime, pi);
    } else {
        alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, nextTime, pi);
    }
```

> Alarm works well and also able to fire Notification with above code.

**i used below code to cancel the Alarm**

```
try {
        Log.e("Cancel Alarm Id---", "" + alarmClockCode);
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, AlarmClockReceiver.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_RECEIVER_FOREGROUND);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable(ALARM_CLOCK, dosesReminder);
        intent.putExtra(ALARM_CLOCK_BUNDLE, bundle);
        intent.putExtra("MedicineName", dosesReminder.getMedicine_name());
        String MedicineTime = "";
        if (dosesReminder.getMorning_dosed().equals("1")) {
            MedicineTime = "1 Morning ";
        }
        if (dosesReminder.getAfter_noon_dosed().equals("1")) {
            MedicineTime = MedicineTime + "1 Afternoon ";
        }
        if (dosesReminder.getEvening_dosed().equals("1")) {
            MedicineTime = MedicineTime + "1 Evening ";
        }
        intent.putExtra("MedicineTime", MedicineTime);

        PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, alarmClockCode,
                intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context
                .getSystemService(Activity.ALARM_SERVICE);
        am.cancel(pi);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

> i also checked the id are same when set and cancel the Alarm but i am unable to cancel the Alarm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i reviewed my code there was a single mistake while canceling the Alarm, that i made as below:

```
 PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, alarmClockCode,
            intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
```

> I used the getActivity method to fetch the Pending Intent object but while creating the Pending Intent Object i used the getBroadcast method.

**Now Issue resolved**

Answer (score 0):

Your Pending intent should be same as request.

```
    PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context,  Integer.parseInt(alarm_id),    intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE)
    alarmManager.cancel(pi)
```

Comment: i used same pending Intent

Comment: The PendingIntent is the identifier to cancel. The pending intent to be cancelled should have set to same action and same data fields,if any have those were used to set the alarm.After setting the same ACTION and data values.

Comment: i have not used the Action. Is Action necessary ?

Comment: i am setting with intent as Extra Data.

Comment: if it is not working Try "PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT"

Comment: but i generated the Alarm with FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT

Comment: change it on both places

Comment: i checked with updating flag with FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT with cancel method but not working trying with both method...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199187/discussion-between-theshaybi-and-rajan-bhavsar).